# How to calculate Log Hazard Ratio in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas

```
proc phreg data = analysis ;  
class c diabetes /descending;  
model days*ind(0) = c diabetes id/ rl ;  
id = c*diabetes;  
hazardratio id;  
run;
```

I am trying to run a simple Cox Regression in SAS. I cant seem to find a way to calculate log-hazard ratio for my variables in the model. The hazard ratio statement and the /rl options gives hazard ratio with 95% CI, but I want log-hazard ratio with 95% CI limits.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get log-hazard ratio just by taking a log of the hazard ratio, the computations are done with the log hazards and exp is taken in the last step of the estimate (please, see an example here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect030.htm). The same applies for Wald and PL CIs (https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_a0000000688.htm), e.g.

> The profile-likelihood confidence limits for the hazard ratio  are obtained by exponentiating these confidence limits